# layer over embedded pdf in IE9 and FF

Tags: html, css, pdf

I've got a problem with positioning a layer over a embedded pdf in IE9 and FF (Chrome and safari works). The layer I want to position over the layer is in IE9 and FF behind the embedded PDF, z-index doesnt work for it.

Is there a workaround, hack, fix or anything that fix my problem?

EDIT

I tried the following:

```
<div id="pdf"><embed id="pdfEmbed" src="file.pdf" height="100%" width="100%" type="application/pdf"></embed></div> 
<div id="layer_over_pdf">some content</div>
```

Both layers with position relative with z-index to sort the layers

I also tried to position an empty Iframe over the embedded pdf. This worked but the problem in IE9 is that the Iframe is not transparant (only the part that falls over the embedded pdf is not transparent but the part of the iframe that falls out of the embedded pdf is transparant, very strange).

Comment: Will you please show your code? What you have tried?

Comment: @A.K I tried to use 2 iframes, 1 to embed the pdf in and 1 empty iframe to put over the other (this is an option but IE9 doesnt allow to be transparant, as far as I can see). I also tried this: <div id="pdf"><embed id="pdfEmbed" src="file.pdf" height="100%" width="100%" type="application/pdf"></embed></div>
<div id="layer_over_pdf">some content</div> Both layers with position relative with z-index to sort the layers

Comment: I would be clearer and more beneficial if you include code in your question statement.

Comment: There is no such element as 'embed' despite what you may have read elsewhere. Use 'object' instead.

Comment: I need to correct my comment because I forgot HTML5 does now have an embed element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after. Let me know if it needs tweaking or isn't what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/fRsUv/

Comment: Thanks but, in chrome it works well but when you test it on IE9 or FF the layer #layer_over_pdf is behind the embedded pdf.

Comment: The content is going behind iFrame in Safari